# Azure Function Queue Trigger Adding Nuget Package

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, nuget-package, azureservicebus

I'm using Azure Function through the Azure Portal for Queue Triggers and I want to add a NuGet Package to it.

There is only two files "run.csx" & "function.json"

The function.json just contains the binding information. However, how do I add a NuGet package such as "Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus" to that function.json. I can't seem to find a clear document or explanation on how to do so.

Comment: Are you asking how to add a nuget package to a project that contains an Azure function?

Comment: Basically, I want to add a nuget package to my azure function I have currently

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#using-nuget-packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#using-nuget-packages), for C# Script (.csx) functions, you can upload a `function.proj` file that contains a `PackageReference` to a nuget package.  This is similar to a .csproj file.  In your case, it should probably be like so:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus" Version="7.1.2" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: ah thanks, didnt know we could just add an .proj file that's why I was a little confused.